# Calling one feature file as background step into another using cucumber ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a feature file A with 8-9 lines of steps which is covering one scenario. Now I need to use feature file A as a background step in feature file B by reducing number of steps to 3-4.

My approach:

- In feature file B - Reduce steps(from feature file A) to 3-4 lines, use helper methods and add as background steps.

Feature file A:

```
Feature: I want to create an event

  Background: User is Logged In
    Given a logged in user

Scenario: Creating an event
  Given I select event
  And I add event details
  And I add start and end time
  Then Timings will be added successfully 
  When I add ticket information and continue
  And Publish my event
  Then I verify event will be created successfully
```

Feature file B

```
Feature: Place an order

Background: Event is created

Given a logged in user

When I select event and fill in required details

Then event should be published
```

I'm concern about duplication. I'm using feature file A as a background step in feature file B by reducing number of steps but functionally both feature files are testing same feature.

Please suggest a better approach if possible. Thank you

Comment: Please show a little bit of code. "Reducing 8-9 lines into 3-4 lines with helper methods and background steps" is quite vague/ambiguous; we really need to see something more concrete to give a proper answer. Also, your question sounds like it *might* be a better fit for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow -- especially if any answers are going to be subjective/opinion-based.

Comment: Apologies!! Updated with code details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So fundamentally using helper methods to reduce number of steps is only something you should do if the compressed steps are also conveying the information correctly. So here is an example (You don't need helpers here either), that would be a good use case.

```
Given I have a party of 2/1/0 # This means adults/children/infants
And the child is under 12
And I am flexible on my flights
And I am going to Spain
When I search for flights
```

```
Given I have Spanish flights displayed # You could also add the pax in here if you wanted
```

Now if you're wanting to use helper methods, that is also fine, but you need to remember cucumber is primarily a tool for encouraging collaboration as well as providing documentation, testing and specification in the same place. So once you try to DRY up your lines, think about whether actually you just want to "compress" the lines down.

i.e.

```
Given('I am {int} years old') do |age|
  @person.age = age
end

Given('my name is {word}') |name|
  @person.name = name
end

Given('my hometown is {string}') |hometown|
  @person.location = hometown
end
```

Can become

```
Given('I am {word}, {int} years old from {string}') |name, age, hometown|
  @person.name = name
  @person.age = age
  @person.location = hometown
end
```

Hopefully some of these tips will have given you some thought.

Comment: Luke Hill -I have updated my post with some code. Thank you for the tips. I will try to compress lines than to reduce it.